# How to change anonymous function variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, anonymous-function

I am working with some example online. I wanted to run the following values with different values of **B0** and **D0** but it is assigned by the anonymous function `lambda`. How can I modify

```
alpha,beta,loc,scale = stats.beta.fit(value)  

error=(scale/(1.96))**2

gpdf = lambda B0, mu, sigma2: 1/np.sqrt(2*pi*sigma2)*np.exp(-1/2*((B0-mu)**2)/sigma2)
approx_sigma2 = lambda scale: (scale/(1.96))**2
ggpdf_v  = lambda B0, D0, error: gpdf(B0, mu=0.8, sigma2=error) * (D0 < 3) + (D0 >= 3) * gpdf(B0, mu=0.5, sigma2=error)
ggpdf_r  = lambda B0, D0, error: gpdf(B0, mu=0.5, sigma2=error)
ggpdf_c  = lambda B0, D0, error: gpdf(B0, mu=0.7, sigma2=error)
ggpdf_v  = lambda B0, D0, error: gpdf(B0, mu=0.9, sigma2=error)
```

Comment: Don't use `lambda` like this. If you are going to name the function use  a `def` statement.

Comment: I tried that but I was getting a lot of errors. Can you post your answer below and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

B0 is a parameter in each of those lambdas. Just like a regular function, you can specify whatever value you want for each parameter when you call it. For example, `gpdf(4, 8, 15)` sets B0 to 4, mu to 8, and sigma2 to 15.

Comment: Can I assign those values outside of the function?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "the function". If you mean "can I assign values outside of the gpdf function?", then yes, that is exactly what my answer describes. If you mean "The entire code sample in my question is inside a function. Can I access gpdf from outside that function?", you can't unless the function explicitly makes gpdf available somehow, perhaps by returning it or assigning it to a variable/attribute in a higher scope. This is not a special rule pertaining to lambdas; that's how all Python variables work.